# Is there a way to run the SVN(Subversion) info command in IntelliJ?

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

is there a way to run the SVN(Subversion) info command in IntelliJ?

I searched in the help, Google and SO but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

What's the point in running standard SVN client **inside** of the IDE? Just start the command prompt and run [`svn info`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.info.html) from there.

Comment: IDEA has support for SVN, and I just want to run info to know which branch I'm on. 
EDIT: Not literally run info, but just get the information of which branch I'm currently on.